# Detect blocked notifications on Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, web-push

Is there a way to detect that the notifications were automatically blocked by Edge?

Recently, instead of seeing the native dialog box to allow or block notifications, I only see that tiny button, which when clicked explains that the notifications are blocked:

[image]

Most users won't notice that tiny button and won't understand why the notifications are not allowed.

I have a code that has been working well for more than a year on Firefox and Chrome. It also used to work on Edge, but recently, Edge only displays that tiny button.

My code works as follow:

- I first display a "Do you wish to receive notifications?" message
- Then if the user clicks "Yes", I call `worker.pushManager.subscribe` which should display the native dialog box from the browser to allow or block notifications.

The problem is that, at least with Edge 112, the subscription never returns, and I don't get any error:

```
try {
    const sub = worker.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly: true,
        applicationServerKey: key
    });

    const result = await sub;

    // Edge never reaches here
    return result;
} catch (error) {
    // Edge never reaches here
}
```

So is there a way to detect that the notifications were automatically blocked by Edge, so that I can mention the tiny button the user should click?

Comment: I agree that this is annoying. I guess that "unfamiliar" means that the user has just landed on the website: maybe displaying the prompt after the user has spent some time on the website may solve the issue. However that is not simple to implement in a simple/reliable way... I had a similar problem with Pushpad and Chrome and I opened this proposal on WICG: https://discourse.wicg.io/t/measuring-user-interaction-time-with-website/5640

Comment: @collimarco The most annoying thing is that as a developer, I don't even know that something went wrong, meaning I can't tell the user about it when it happens. Also, in my case, the user must first log in to access the website, then an HTML popup asks him if he want to allow notifications. That used to be enough for Edge. I guess I'll have to detect Edge and show a warning about that tiny button, as notification is a must for our users.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's Edge's [Quiet notification requests](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2021/02/16/introducing-adaptive-notification-requests-in-microsoft-edge/).

I tried many ways but seems that we can't detect the "Quiet notification requests". Usually, we use [`Notification.permission`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission) to check the permission values, but the value doesn't change and it's always `default` when the notification is blocked quietly.

There's little we can do about it. The way you mention to detect Edge and show a reminder can be a workaround. Besides, you can also provide feedback to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge if you have any suggestion about the "Quiet notification requests".

Comment: For now I've decided to add a loading dialog box that disappears once the user explicitly allows or cancels notifications, and I've added some explanation for Edge users.